# Not able to play Sound with this code

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am using below code in my app to play the Sound.
But i am not able to play it.
Whats the Problem ??

Code:

```
public void playSound(int resources){
    try{
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;
        MediaPlayer  mPlayer=null;
        if (mStartPlaying==true){
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://MY_PACKAGE/" + resources);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } 
        else{
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
        mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }


}
```

And i get log cat as like below:

```
05-09 05:24:22.272: VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(95): Completed command PLAYER_INIT status=PVMFFailure
05-09 05:24:22.272: ERROR/PlayerDriver(95): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
05-09 05:24:22.272: ERROR/MediaPlayer(8072): error (1, -1)
05-09 05:24:22.272: ERROR/AudioPlayTest(8072): prepare() failed
05-09 05:24:22.282: VERBOSE/PVPlayer(95): run_set_video_surface s=-2147483648, cancelled=0
05-09 05:24:22.282: VERBOSE/PlayerDriver(95): HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
05-09 05:24:22.282: WARN/PlayerDriver(95): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
```

Comment: maybe you're trying to play unsupported format.

Comment: @rosco: I am going to play wav file and its in raw directory.

Comment: do you know what fails? : new, setDataSource, prepare, start ... moreover IOException tells you there is something wrong with input file, such FileNotFoundException or EOFException (try to printout a more specific exception as suggested here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html)

Comment: @rosco: Yes, you are right. I am using wav as file formate but its not supported in it. Now i have converted it in to the mp3 and it works fine.

Comment: @rosco: Please put your answer here so i can accept it as right one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to play unsupported format.
Do you know what fails? : new, setDataSource, prepare, start ... moreover IOException tells you there is something wrong with input file, such FileNotFoundException or EOFException (try to printout a more specific exception as suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html))

ps.: moved comments in answer.